# Use Yocto recipes to clone Git repositories

Tags: git, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I have a bunch of Yocto recipe files that contain the configs for various git repositories in the format

```
SRC_URI = "git://XXX;protocol=ssh;branch=YYY;"
SRCREV = "abc123"
```

I am wondering if I can use these files to *only* clone the git repositories at the configured branch + commit hash. I want to then build these repos separately (not using Yocto/Bitbake)

I came across [git.py](https://github.com/openembedded/bitbake/blob/master/lib/bb/fetch2/git.py) from Bitbake's source code which seems to perform the clone operations in Bitbake. I could write a wrapper around this module, but wondering if there is a pre-built command that would let me invoke this module using Bitbake.

Answer (score 1):

You can see in [`openembedded/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/git.py`](https://github.com/openembedded/bitbake/blob/d2cb388f58a37db2149fad34e4572d954e6e5441/lib/bb/fetch2/git.py#L367-L376) an example of clone as you mention:

```py
        # If the repo still doesn't exist, fallback to cloning it
        if not os.path.exists(ud.clonedir):
            # We do this since git will use a "-l" option automatically for local urls where possible
            if repourl.startswith("file://"):
                repourl = repourl[7:]
            clone_cmd = "LANG=C %s clone --bare --mirror %s %s --progress" % (ud.basecmd, shlex.quote(repourl), ud.clonedir)
            if ud.proto.lower() != 'file':
                bb.fetch2.check_network_access(d, clone_cmd, ud.url)
            progresshandler = GitProgressHandler(d)
            runfetchcmd(clone_cmd, d, log=progresshandler)
```

You would have to code something similar (without the `--bare` option in your case) to clone your own repository.

---

The [OP Daddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2759910/daddy) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74468423/use-yocto-recipes-to-clone-git-repositories/74470954?noredirect=1#comment131479985_74470954):

> I unblocked myself by writing a simple shell script that greps for the `SRC_URI/SRCREV` and extracts the relevant details.

Comment: I unblocked myself by writing a simple shell script that greps for the SRC_URI/SRCREV and extracts the relevant details, I will try this soon. Thanks!

Comment: @Daddy That is a possible workaround indeed. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.